# How do multiple users connected to a wireless router receive their signals?

Tags: rf, wireless

In other words how does a wireless router with multiple users work? I know that routers use electromagnetic waves radio waves, but how does information get sent to the user it is intended to? and if the router emits all signals in a particular frequency(at least that is how I think it works) does this in theory mean that information can be captured by one user that the information was not intended for just by being in the proximity of the network?

Answer (score 5):

All nodes in a wireless network receive the same information from the wi-fi accesspoint. Each frame contains information about source and destination MAC address. When a node receives a frame, its network adapter checks destination address and discards all frames with different address, unless it is in promiscuitous mode.

When encryption is employed, only the intended recipient is able to decrypt the received frame.